# Wordpress's WooCommerce Plugin compatibility with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a web server that has PHP 5.3 installed and as per our clients requirement we need to use WooCommerce on the WordPress website . In the Woocommerce 2.3.7 plugin page on WordPress site, its recommended php 5.2 or greater while after installation it says php 5.4 version is required.

We cannot upgrade the PHP due to some other dependencies . We also tried the plugin on our WordPress site with php 5.3 and it worked fine. we did not find any issues.

I would like to know what will be the impact or what things will not work if we tried woocommerce 2.37 on php 5.3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WooCommerce Server Requirements](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/server-requirements/) state that the minimum acceptable version of PHP is the same as for WordPress... 5.2.4. Though I would highly recommend getting a better host who can provide you with at least 5.4.